# How to Get python print result in one line for 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, multidimensional-array, arraylist

class Passenger:

```
def __init__(self, name, IsBooked):
    self.name = name
    self.IsBooked = IsBooked
```

Seats = [[0]*2]*2

for i in range(2):

```
for j in range(2):
    Seats[i][j] = Passenger('', False)
```

for i in range(2):

```
for j in range(2):
    if(Seats[i][j].IsBooked == False):
        print('X')
print('\n')
```

I want to print the output as

X X

X X

But I am getting the result as

[image: I am getting the result as]

Where Should I modify the code to get the expected result?

Comment: As an aside, `Seats = [[0]*2]*2` is not doing what you think it is. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly

Comment: You're literally printing `\n` on every iteration of `for i` - what did you expect? Unindent that `print('\n')` line and done

Answer (score 0):

```
class Passenger:
    def __init__(self, name, IsBooked):
        self.name = name
        self.IsBooked = IsBooked


Seats = [[0]*2]*2
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        Seats[i][j] = Passenger('', False)

for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        if(Seats[i][j].IsBooked == False):
            print('X', end='')
```

You will need to remove `print('\n')` in last line as it is being executed after every two elements.

Comment: I want result as.                                             X X                                                                 X X                                                             But after removing that line I am getting X in new line each time I want to print in same line

Comment: ohh print function ends with '\n' escape sequence (new line) by default. You can give another argument `end=''` in function. Your new print function will become 
`print('X', end='')`

Answer (score 0):

OK

```py
class Passenger:
    def __init__(self, name, IsBooked):
        self.name = name
        self.IsBooked = IsBooked


txt = ''
Seats = [[0]*2]*2
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        Seats[i][j] = Passenger('', False)

for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        if(Seats[i][j].IsBooked == False):
            txt += 'X '
            txt_with_new_line += 'X\n'

    print(txt + '\n')
    txt = ''
#   Result
#   X X
#
#   X X
```